# In cakephp how can I do a find with conditions on a related field?

Tags: php, cakephp

I've got a model (Listings) that has and belongs to a few different models, I'd like to find all of this model where it's related model (Openhouses) have a condition. The 'has and belongs to' are setup in the model files. Listings hasmany Openhouses and Openhouses belong to Listings. (And listings has many and blongs to a few other models where I want the data.)

I've been trying.

```
$this->Listing->find('all', 
array('conditions' => 
array('Openhouse.date >' => $openhouse_start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
'Openhouse.date <' => $openhouse_end->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
));
```

but to no avail.

```
Error: 1054: Unknown column 'Openhouse.date' in 'where clause
```

I know I can search on the Openhouse model and get related Listings but then the data is returned in a different format and I need to turn recursion way up to get data from my other models. (And I end up with duplicate openhouse data!). I can post some more code examples if needed.

My question is basically do I need to just query the openhouse model and live with it or is my syntax for putting conditions on related models incorrect?

Comment: This is really useful for me but is it also possible to sorting by the Openhouse.date field. When i tried in my example which is same with this one it has no sense.I debuged the queries and sorting field and the join is in separated queries. $this->List->find('all', array( 'contain' => array( 'Openhouse.conditions' => array( 'Openhouse.date >' => $openhouse_start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 'Openhouse.date <' => $openhouse_end->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')) ), 'Openhouse.order' => array( 'Openhouse.date DESC' ) ) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$this->List->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Openhouse.conditions' => array(
            'Openhouse.date >' => $openhouse_start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'Openhouse.date <' => $openhouse_end->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Works like a charm thanks! (sorry for the delay I got sick this weekend - but I'm finally back to work)

Comment: could one also specify conditions on the top-level model (List) in this example?

could I just add this 

'conditions' => array('List.name LIKE'=>'foo%'),

right after 

find('all', array(

Answer (score 2):

If you have a lot of linked models, settings recursive to 2 might bring more data than you might want.

If that is true, there is an alternative to what mavarro said, you can also try using the [Containable behaviour](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html):

```
$this->Listing->find
(
    'all', 
    array
    (
        'conditions' => array
        (
            'Openhouse.date >' => $openhouse_start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'Openhouse.date <' => $openhouse_end->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        ),
        'contain' => array('Openhouse')
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a
`$this->Listing->recursive = 2;`
before the call to find all. That *should* link up the tables before the call giving you access to the Openhouse model from the Listing model.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->List->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Openhouse.date >' => $openhouse_start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'Openhouse.date <' => $openhouse_end->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                             ),
        'order' => array('Openhouse.date DESC')
                      )
                             )
)
```