# CakePHP - Find conditions for related model

Tags: cakephp

I have SubjectGroup, which hasMany Subject.

```
class SubjectGroup extends AppModel {

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Subject' => array('order' => 'Subject.name')
    );

}

class Subject extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array('SubjectGroup');

}
```

I want to get all SubjectGroups, and recursively retrieve their Subjects, but only the Subjects that have a status of 2.  I can't figure out how to do this.

```
$subjectGroups = $this->SubjectGroup->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('Subject.status !=' => 2),
    'order' => 'SubjectGroup.name'
));
```

**Warning (512): SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'Subject.status' in 'where clause'**

Note: I have read that I can add a conditions array to the model relationship definition, but I don't want the relationship to always use the condition.  Sometimes I will want to just retrieve the SubjectGroups and Subjects with status 2, and sometimes the SubjectGroups with all Subjects, regardless of their status.

**PROGRESS**

With some help from Ross, I now am trying to use the Containable behaviour.  I have this so far:

```
$this->SubjectGroup->find('all', array(
    'contain' => 'Subject.status != 2',
    'order' => 'SubjectGroup.name'
));
```

There are no errors, but it returns all Subjects, even the ones with status = 2.

Comment: Same problem here. Do you solve your problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditions in associated models using Model->find() (CakePHP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751686/conditions-in-associated-models-using-model-find-cakephp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is asking Cake to look for the field `status` in the `SubjectGroup` table. It doesn't exist.

What you really want to do is use containable behaviour, and access the `status` field this way.

Try this:

```
$this->SubjectGroup->Behaviors->attach('Containable');

$subjectGroups = $this->SubjectGroup->find('all', array(
    'contain'=>array('Subject'=>array(
                             'conditions' => array('Subject.status !=' => 2))
                    ),
    'order' => 'SubjectGroup.name'
    ));
```

Comment: Yep, Containable looks like what I need, but your code didn't work.  According to the manual, it has an example of `$this->Post->find('all', array('contain' => 'Comment.author = "Daniel"'));`

So I tried modifying it to  `$this->SubjectGroup->find('all', array('contain' => 'Subject.status != 2', 'order' => 'SubjectGroup.name'));` but that doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post your associations? And what didn't work? error, unexpected data?

Comment: See my updated main post.  No errors, it just returns all Subjects so the containable behaviour doesn't appear to be doing anything.

Comment: This answer should not be accepted, since it returns ALL SubjectGroups, but each of them only includes Subjects with status != 2.

Comment: Yes! I am agree with Vanja D.