# CakePHP 3.0 - How can I use contain on a model I've just contained?

Tags: mysql, query-builder, cakephp-3.0

Here's my issue, and my tables:

```
**sales_person**
id | sp_number | name
31 | 23948223  | John Doe

**Team**
id  |    name    | parent_id | lft | rght
52  | Super Team |     1     |  1  |  2

**Team_Salesmen**
id | team_id | sales_person_id
1  |    52   |      31
```

So I have my sales people, my teams, and a table to show which salespeople belong to which teams.

I was going to display a list of all of a team's children teams, then list all of their salespeople.

Teams is related to Team_salesmen by the team_id, so I can do a contain on that. The trouble is, this only returns the Team_salesmen entity 'id:1, team_id:52, sales_person_id:31', whereas I need it to return the name and number of the salesman.

So, while in the Teams model I need to contain with TeamSalesmen and then contain from TeamSalesmen to SalesPerson. How can I chain commands? CakePHP thinks I'm trying to contain Teams to SalesPersons, which aren't related directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...I feel stupid now. I was browsing the old CakePHP posts on this and found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751686/conditions-in-associated-models-using-model-find-cakephp).

So I just tried:

```
->contain(['TeamSalesmen' => ['SalesPerson']])
```

Just for kicks, and it worked. *facepalm*

Awesome!

Comment: It's also explained in detail [**in the cookbook**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#loading-associations).